# Converting an async call to RxJava, how to manually complete after all items are processed?

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage, rx-java2

I have a custom class for uploading either a single file or multiple files to Firebase Storage:

```
public class FirebaseUploader {
    private Context appContext;
    private FirebaseStorage storage;

    public FirebaseUploader(Context appContext) {
        this.appContext = appContext;
        this.storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    }

    // Uploading a single file
    public Observable<String> send(Uri file) {
        return toObservable(Observable.just(file));
    }

    // Uploading multiple files
    public Observable<String> send(List<Uri> files) {
        return toObservable(Observable.fromIterable(files));
    }

    private Observable<String> toObservable(Observable<Uri> observable) {
        return observable.flatMap(this::upload);
    }

    private Observable<String> upload(Uri file) {
        return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
                StorageReference branch = storage.getReference().child("images");
                StorageReference leaf = branch.child(generateUniqueId(file));
                UploadTask uploadTask = leaf.putFile(file);

                uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) emitter.onError(task.getException());
                        return leaf.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                            String url = downloadUri.toString();
                            emitter.onNext(url);
                            //emitter.onComplete();
                        } else {
                            // Handle failures
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private String generateUniqueId(Uri file) {
        String fileType = appContext.getContentResolver().getType(file);
        String extension = (fileType.equals("image/jpeg")) ? ".jpg" : ".png";
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return fileName + extension;
    }
}
```

It actually took me several days to come up with this solution because I initially had no clue how to convert the Firebase async calls to RxJava. Then I was stuck for quite a while wondering why the observable was not completing, until I eventually realized I was calling `emitter.onNext` and `emitter.onError`, but there was no `emitter.onComplete` anywhere in my code!

So `emitter.onComplete` is inside the `OnCompleteListener`. But it's commented out — that's not where that call should be. What I've been searching for is a way to call `.onComplete()` on the `emitter` only after all the files have been processed. With my limited experience with RxJava, the only way I'm seeing is first doing a count of the number of files to be uploaded, then manually completing the sequence when that count is reached. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your `emitter.onComplete()` is exactly where it should be.

The Observable returned from your `upload` method is responsible for one thing only: uploading the single file specified by the Uri parameter.  That task is done when the `UploadTask` completes, so you should call `onComplete` at that time.

The `flatMap` operator is responsible for collecting all of these results into a single `Observable`.  It will emit `onComplete` downstream when all files have been uploaded, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, if it's a single file. But when there are multiple files, the subscriber gets only the first file and the observable completes. That's not what I'm expecting.

Comment: @Duos Each individual file upload observable sends `onComplete` to an observer internal to the `flatMap` implementation.  Only after all of these upstream observables complete will your own subscriber receive `onComplete`.

Comment: My bad. You are right — hence my upvote. Further debugging has made me understand that indeed all the items are flowing one after the other — except the last item, and it's what led me to mistakenly believe the sequence was completing after the first item. So either the subscriber is not receiving that last item, or the emitter is not emitting it. Can you give me any clues?